# Fancybox asynchronous behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm having an issue with fancybox. When I load the fancybox, the viewport darkens like normal but it seems that the next line of code is running before my fancybox completely loads.

Ex:

```
 alert("first");
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'href' : 'form.html',
        'width' : '30%',
        'height' : '50%',
        'type' : 'iframe'
    });
alert("done");
```

When my codes runs, first is alerted, then the viewport darkens and then done is alerted, and then my fancybox loads.

Is there a way to stop this asynchronous behavior and instead change it so that nothing after the fancybox code will execute until after fancybox closes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to "pause" the script for the fancybox execution,
you have to put the alert in the onClosed callback:

```
alert("first");
jQuery.fancybox({
    'href' : 'form.html',
    'width' : '30%',
    'height' : '50%',
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'onClosed': function(){ alert(done)}
});
```

Comment: but why is it that fancybox is behaving asynchronously?

Comment: because it can load asynchronic content with ajax, and will not interrump the normal function of the scripts of the page

Comment: Because there is no way to render a completely separate page (form.html) inside an iframe, synchronously. It goes against the most fundamental design of web browsers. Most browsers won't even try to render DOM changes made by javascript until after the JS finishes executing, let alone pause the JS while it renders an iframe.